# Calculating Holiday Sales on next Workday in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, reporting

I am facing an issue with a measure that calculates sales for the next business day when it falls on a weekend. Currently, my measure (Sales1) is written as follows:

```
Sales1 = 
VAR Current_day = MIN(Date[Date])
VAR Saturday = MIN(Date[Date]) - 2 

RETURN 
IF (
   WEEKDAY(Current_day) = 1 || WEEKDAY(Current_day) = 7,
   BLANK(),
   IF (
       WEEKDAY(Current_day) = 2,
       CALCULATE (
           [Sales],
           FILTER (
               ALL (Date[Date]),
               Date[Date] >= Saturday && Date[Date] <= Current_day
           )
       ),
       [Sales]
   )
)
```

However, I now have a column "Holidays" in my Date table, which indicates whether a day is a holiday with an "x". I want to modify the measure to include the calculation of sales for the next business day after a holiday, similar to how it is currently done for weekends.

For example, if Friday is a holiday, then on Monday, the sales for Friday, Saturday, and Sunday should be calculated. Similarly, if Monday is a holiday, then on Tuesday, the sales for Saturday, Sunday, and Monday should be calculated.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to adjust the measure to include holidays for the calculation of weekend sales.

Thank you in advance for your help.